# Servlet [example] in web application [/SpringMvcDemo] threw load() exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I have been trying to run a simple Spring MVC project named SpringMvcDemo by following the spring mvc documentation. When I try to run the project , I am getting the load() exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet. I have been stuck for days. Any help would be highly appreciated.

full stacktrace

```
Jul 18, 2020 12:45:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [example] in web application [/SpringMvcDemo] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1042)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4864)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
```

**web.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>SpringMvcDemo</display-name>
  
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**example-servlet.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd" >
     
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.controller"></context:component-scan>
     
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
     
</beans>
```

controller class **ExampleController.java**

```
package com.spring.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class ExampleController {
    
    @RequestMapping("/example")
    public ModelAndView example() {
        
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("example");
        return model;
    }
}
```

project file structure
[image: project file structure]

[image]

P.S: I have added all the Spring jars to my project class path

Comment: Which "Spring MVC documentation", specifically? Modern Spring applications are written with Spring Boot, which eliminates the need for most of this. (You can generate a project ready for you to write your controllers at start.spring.io. I recommend Thymeleaf instead of JSP; it's a newer replacement.)

Comment: this one [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

Comment: Please note that that is for Spring 3.0. Unfortunately, Google has a habit of returning search results to that version (I complained about it just today at work), but the current version of Spring is **5.2**. Version 3.0 is _more than 10 years old_. Just go to https://start.spring.io, select "Web MVC" and Thymeleaf (or JSP if you must), and you'll be ready to go.

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/, https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Answer (score 0):

in example-servlet.xml try using internal resource view resolver instead of UrlBasedViewResolver

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
```

else try this link too hope it helps

https://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-servlet-dispatcherservlet-exception-spring-mvc-tomcat-and-404-error/

Comment: tried InternalResourceViewResolver, still facing the same issue

Comment: I have tried the Deployment Assembly method mentioned in the above link before posting it here. But I get completely different error when  I do that. In that case the Tomcat Server fails to start with the error "Starting Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost has encountered a problem" `A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SpringMvcDemo]]`

Comment: there must be some dependency problem then probably try using maven and let maven handle all such dependencies.

Comment: yeah you were right, i let maven handle all the spring dependencies and its working fine